# Developing API using Rails 5.x

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I need to develop a Rails based API which takes in a JSON input with parent and child data (Customer and his Cars), and stores them in User and Car tables respectively.

I am currently learning from [Developing API using Rails 5](https://www.simplify.ba/articles/2016/06/18/creating-rails5-api-only-application-following-jsonapi-specification/)

However, the above example uses two Controllers for each table. I need one single Transaction. Are there any resources to learn how to save in multiple tables in one block using Rails 5 API ?

Answer (score 1):

You need to use nested attributes , by using this you can save parent & child form in a single save . For more details , check http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/NestedAttributes/ClassMethods.html